# Convert US number format to EU

Tags: excel, number-formatting

Is it possoble to convert US number format (comma as thousand separator) to EU (dot as thousand separator) with formula or function, like NUMBERVALUE(A2,",",".") for EU to US?

(e.g. 5,000.15 to 5.000,15)

I know that there is an option to use or not use system separator (advanced options), but in that case "," in formulas is changed in ";" as argument separator, and I would like to avoid that.

I was thinking converting numerical value to string, then with right and mid function to add separator, but I am unable to successfully do that.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** 
So this is what I figured. It's not best solution 'cause value can not be used in further calculations (string) before converting it again to numeric value.

So first, numeric value is converted to str with this function (function is written poorly, I know) so it at least looks like EU number format.

```
Function ConvertToEU(s As String, decpl As Integer)


'Checks if integer
Dim pos As Integer
pos = InStr(s, ".")

Dim decpart As String: decpart = ""
Dim LArray() As String
Dim temp1

If pos <> 0 Then
LArray = Split(s, ".")
temp1 = LArray(0)
decpart = LArray(1)
Else
temp1 = s
End If

Dim dectemp As Integer: dectemp = decpl - Len(decpart)


If dectemp > 0 Then
For i = 1 To dectemp
decpart = decpart & 0
Next

ElseIf dectemp < 0 Then

decpart = Left(decpart, decpl)

Else

End If


Dim LenSTR As Double: LenSTR = Len(temp1) / 3

Dim cond As Boolean

If CStr(CLng(LenSTR)) = LenSTR Then
cond = True
Else: cond = False
End If

Dim start As String: start = ""
Dim rest As String
If cond = False Then
start = Left(temp1, Len(temp1) - Int(LenSTR) * 3) & "."
rest = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(temp1, Left(temp1, Len(temp1) - Int(LenSTR) * 3), "")
Else
rest = temp1
End If

Dim x As Integer: x = 1
Dim temp As String
Dim conv As String
For i = 1 To Int(LenSTR) - 1
If cond = False Then
Debug.Print "X"
conv = conv & Mid(rest, x, 3) & "."
temp = temp & Mid(rest, x, 3)
x = x + 3
Else
conv = conv & Mid(rest, x, 3) & "."
temp = temp & Mid(rest, x, 3)
x = x + 3
End If

Next


If Len(decpart) > 0 Then
ConvertToEU = start & conv & Right(rest, 3) & "," & decpart
Else
ConvertToEU = start & conv & Right(rest, 3)
End If


End Function
```

**EDIT 2:** 
Corrected for decimal places.

Converting it again to numeric value

```
Function ConvertToVal(s As String)

ConvertToVal = CDbl(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(s, ".", ""), ",", "."))

    End Function
```

Is it possible to do this properly, keeping value as numeric?

Comment: Leave the numerical value alone and specify a different [NumberFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-numberformat-property-excel) for the cells.

Comment: That is not possible, changing format with text function will result in just changing decimal separator, but not thousand.